# UiTextField Password Protected Issues

Tags: iphone, uitextfield

I am placing 4 consecutive UITextFields in a PinCode Set Up Screen. Now I have made those UiTextFields "Password Protected", but the problem is when I enter any character in the TextField, it First shows that character then convert it into * (or a DOT). just like its default behavior.

Now is there any way that when i start typing in that field it does not show me that character and just keep on printing DOT or a * in the field.

Thanks

Comment: i found same behavior in almost all  platforms. Have you seen the behavior as you mentioned above  in any platform ? I don't think this is possible .

Comment: @VXtreme , wel You know The iPhone default PinCode feature has this functionality. Also if you talk about some other platform then in Android Check the pinCode functionality of DropBox Application (both in Android and in iPhone)

Comment: This might be the default behavior for password textfields on iphone. The plaintext letter appears and after 2 seconds or when you've typed the next letter it is converted into a •

Answer (score 1):

```
You can do one thing.. 

this is .h file------>

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#define fontRegular @"Helvetica Neue"
#define fontBold @"HelveticaNeue-Bold"


@interface ABCViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>

{
    NSString *strReturn;
}

@property(nonatomic,retain)NSString *strReturn;

@end



this is .m file--->

#import "ABCViewController.h"



@implementation ABCViewController

@synthesize strReturn;





-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


    UITextField *txt_Fields= [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30, 0, 230, 44)];
    txt_Fields.backgroundColor= [UIColor clearColor];
    txt_Fields.delegate= self;
    txt_Fields.clearButtonMode=YES;
    txt_Fields.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
    [txt_Fields setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:fontRegular size:20.0]];
    [txt_Fields setTextColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:105.0/255 green:105.0/255 blue:105.0/255 alpha:1.0]];
    txt_Fields.borderStyle=UITextBorderStyleBezel;
    txt_Fields.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
    txt_Fields.keyboardType=UIKeyboardTypeURL;
    txt_Fields.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone;
    [self.view addSubview:txt_Fields];
    [txt_Fields release];

}



- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    self.strReturn=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",strReturn,string];
    textField.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@*",textField.text];
    NSLog(@"str:- %@",self.strReturn);
    return NO;
}


Note:-
But In this case you will have to maintain string manually, Means You will have to store the string in a string variable, you can not take textfield.text, because it will return - "****". And you will have to manage so many things manuaaly....
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible. This feature is unavailable in apple.

Comment: any other (cracked ) way, we can do that ??? u know using some uitextfield delegates

Comment: SORRY, i don't know about jailbreak,but it cannot be done using apple's conventional way i.e. using uitextfield's delegate method. I never seen what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @RKY:and have you seen the feature he mentioned in any mobile platform ?

Comment: @VXtreme , wel You know The iPhone default PinCode feature has this functionality. Also if you talk about some other platform then in Android Check the pinCode functionality of DropBox Application (both in Android and in iPhone)

Answer (score 0):

Remember, this is a mobile device with a small keyboard. Showing the key that is pressed for a split second just reassure the user that they press the correct key. Also because its a mobile device, the user should be the only one looking at the screen. If the user is doing using AirPlay to share the screen, they should turn it off before enter password information.

Answer (score 0):

You may see this example: https://github.com/Koolistov/Passcode I hope that helps you.